# Apple SignIn issue while submission on AppStore

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-sign-in

We are using AppleSignIn in our Flutter App, it works fine in all conditions from our side, but we are trying to launch the App in Apple Store, but the developer team keeps on rejecting that the Apple Signin not works.

We had tested with both debug and release mode, everything works fine.

According to the error message shown from their side, throughout our understanding,
the below code returns email = null, even at initial login

```
final credential = await SignInWithApple
                                        .getAppleIDCredential(
                                      scopes: [
                                        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
                                        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
                                      ],
                                    );
print('mailId-----${credential.email}');
```

Plugin we are using,

```
sign_in_with_apple: ^3.3.0
```

But we had searched all in internet, that none of the condition which return null at initial condition, but through our code, we printed a Toast, so that we are saying that at initial condition it may returns null from Apple Team side, but they're not letting us know the exact condition of that issue,

We are searching for more than a week, expecting a help!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually with apple signin, you can only get the email credentials at the very first time of login.After no matter how many time you try it keeps on giving you null.

So You have to some how store the credentials at the very first time in your Remote DB, so that even if you pass null value it will find the credentials from your db accordingly.

If you have missed at the first time then you want to get the gmail from users some how means, what you can do is if the sign in with apple returns email null, show dialog to enter the gmail and let them enter it then register with it.

I hope this helps you !

Comment: Yes... actually the one we'd done with the same as you said in first point, but im not sure with the second point ,do the apple team will accept this? Have you launched with the same in APPSTORE before?

Comment: Yes, If the login and register flow works as expected no need to worry about it.

Comment: Okay thanks , let me try with it